# What is the process and the cost of creating a web scraper with 100 websites?

Tags: python, web-scraping, data-science

I need to create a web-scraper with at least 100 websites. None of them offers any kind of APIs or RSS. Scraping is the only option. I made my research but couldn't find detailed information about scraping. What technologies I need to focus on this project and If I want to work with Data Scientist how much it would ideally cost? I am quite new to programming but trying to figure out how to create such a thing.

I have already created an automated process for RSS based websites. I am getting information into Airtable. But I am expected to create a more sophisticated solution for websites who don't offer RSS.

I am thinking about using Python with Selenium and BeautifulSoup frameworks for scraping and turning this data into something useful. Then I will create a search tool on top of this database and people will be able to use filters to get the desired information. The last step is creating automatic documents based on filter results but this can be solved with G-drive doc API.

Answer (score 0):

> how much it would ideally cost?

Can be done without spending a penny. Run your own server, or look for free/paid python server hostings that suit your need. Code yourself, or pay someone to do it. Again, depends upon the exact workload.

> What technologies I need to focus on this project?

You already answered your question. Python with BeautifulSoup is sufficient for hobby projects. Learn about micro web framework such as Flask or Django for your search tool.